# ORB FeatureDetector with Bag Of Words

Tags: opencv, image-recognition, orb

`BOWImgDescriptorExtractor` has to receive 32F so `SURF` or `SIFT` have to be used for the `DescriptorExtractor`, but for the `FeatureDetector` surely that can be any you wish, right?

I just need some clarification here, I've only ever seen people say that *"You can't use `ORB` with `Bow`"* but when detecting the features, why would it matter which you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't think it's matter. You can use arbitrary methods for feature point detection (i.e. ORB, FAST, SIFT, SURF, etc.).

The problem may come from the next step, from feature point description, for the reasons stated by Guanta in [their answer here](http://See%20also%20Guanta's%20answer%20[here][1].%20%20%20[1]:%20http://answers.opencv.org/question/24835/is-there-a-way-of-using-orb-with-bow/?answer=24858#post-id-24858):

> The link you posted, gives one possibilty to solve the issue of binary descriptors by simple conversion to float (CV_32F) and relies on the fact that OpenCV's k-means algorithm can only deal with CV_32F and uses L2-distance for comparison. Thus, the binary descriptors may however also cluster in a wrong way (since actually you want to have a Hamming distance measure)!

That's why it's recommended to use of SIFT/SURF descriptors. But apart from it, you can mix the different kind of feature point detectors with different kind of descriptors.

Comment: Well i'm using logos, and with `SURF` it would detect feature points on and around the logos (ie in the background - even if white) but with `ORB`, as its much better at edge detection, it was much better at getting just the logo. -- To clarify i'm using `ORB` for the feature detector and `SURF` for the descriptor extractor

Comment: I think the most important criteria of feature detectors are speed, quality and repeatability in different lighting and scale conditions. Below you find two comparisons of OpenCV's feature detection algorithms, but your idea can work in practice. [Comparison #1](http://computer-vision-talks.com/articles/2011-07-13-comparison-of-the-opencv-feature-detection-algorithms/) and [comparison #2](http://computer-vision-talks.com/articles/2011-01-04-comparison-of-the-opencv-feature-detection-algorithms/).

Comment: This is why I want to use ORB, but its a lot harder to work around using [K-Majority to get a Bag Of Words model with ORB](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/236010493_A_Fast_Approach_for_Integrating_ORB_Descriptors_in_the_Bag_of_Words_Model) then simply using SURF or SIFT. I am more curious as to why this isn't an approach that I'd seen before.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly, the pseudo-code associated with your title's question would be :

```
# Construct vocabulary
bow_trainer = cv2.BOWKMeansTrainer(50)
bow_trainer.add(np.float32(descriptors))
vocab = bow_trainer.cluster().astype(descriptor.dtype)

# Create an object for computing global image BoW descriptors
bow_descr = cv2.BOWImgDescriptorExtractor(ORBdetector, CV2.BFMatcher(CV.NORM_HAMMING))
bow_descr.setVocabulary(vocab)

# Load an image, find keypoints, compute global image descriptor
img = cv2.imread("PathtoImage", ...)
keypoints = detector.detect(img,None)
description = bow_descr.compute(img, kps)

# Visualization
plt.figure( ...)

# Distance calculation (assuming you have two histograms, stored each in the "description" variable)
dist = 1 - cv2.compareHist(pic1.description, pic2.description, cv2.HISTCMP_CORREL)
```